# choose which columns to display when using Boolean filtering in pandas for python

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, filtering

Is there a way to only show certain columns from a dataset when displaying data after using a **Boolean filter**?

Here is my code:

```
birth_year = int(input("What year were you born? "))
if birth_year >= 1980 and birth_year <= 2017:
    print(videogames[videogames['Year'] == birth_year].head(5))
```

And this is my output:

```
What year were you born? 2000
Column                                Name Platform  Year         Genre  \
Rank                                                                      
133                Pokémon Crystal Version       GB  2000  Role-Playing   
174                       Final Fantasy IX       PS  2000  Role-Playing   
224                               Driver 2       PS  2000        Action   
226               Tony Hawk's Pro Skater 2       PS  2000        Sports   
243     Dragon Quest VII: Warriors of Eden       PS  2000  Role-Playing   

Column         Publisher  NA_Sales  EU_Sales  JP_Sales  Other_Sales  \
Rank                                                                  
133             Nintendo      2.55      1.56      1.29         0.99   
174           SquareSoft      1.62      0.77      2.78         0.14   
224                Atari      2.36      2.10      0.02         0.25   
226           Activision      3.05      1.41      0.02         0.20   
243     Enix Corporation      0.20      0.14      4.10         0.02   

Column  Global_Sales  
Rank                  
133             6.39  
174             5.30  
224             4.73  
226             4.68  
243             4.47
```

Can I have it where it only displays the columns Rank, Name, Year, and Platform?

Comment: `df[['Rank', 'Name', 'Year', 'Platform']]`

Comment: Or for use with the filtering, `videogames.loc[condition, columns]`